# comparison between the string and pointer

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, c-strings, string-comparison

I'm trying the following codes, but got unexpected result.

```
//the first element in argv[] is a
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char a;
    
    if (*argv ==  "a")
    {
        printf("a");
    }
    
}
```

I got nothing after excution, so that means the condition `*argv++ ==  "a"` is false. So why?

Comment: C does not allow comparison of array contents with "==".  You must iterate over the arrays and compare each element.

Comment: There is a library function `strcmp()` which will do this for you. `if(strcmp(argv[1], "a") == 0)`

Comment: you cannot compare strings in c, you must use ```strcmp``` to compare two strings.

Answer (score 1):

In this if statement

```
if (*argv ==  "a")
```

there are compared two pointers. The first one is the pointer to the first character of the string pointed to by the pointer `*argv` and the second one is the pointer to the first character of the string literal `"a"`.

As these two strings occupy different extents of memory then the comparison of the pointers always evaluates to logical false.

If you want to compare pointed strings then you need to use the standard C string function `strcmp`. For example

```
if ( strcmp( *argv, "a" ) == 0 )
```

If you want to compare first characters of the strings then you should write

```
if ( **argv ==  *"a" )
```

or just use the character `'a'` instead of the string literal that is more natural

```
if ( **argv ==  'a' )
```

Pay attention to that if `*argv` is not equal to `NULL` then this pointer points to the string that denotes the running program.

Maybe you actually mean the following if statement

```
if ( argc > 1 && strcmp( argv[1], "a" ) == 0 )
```

if you want to check whether the first command line argument is equal tp the string literal `"a"`.

Answer (score 1):

char *argv[] is an array of pointers to char.

```
    // myapp.c - program to print out all command line parameters
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int i ;
        for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            printf ("arg %d = %s\n", i + 1, argv[i]) ;
        }
        return 0 ;
    }
```

If one were to compile this code and run it at the command line like this:

```
myapp This That another
```

It would print out

```
arg 1 = myapp
arg 2 = This
arg 3 = That
arg 4 = another
```

So, let's say *argv points to 0x0800001000 (in RAM) and "a" is held at address 0x090000000 (in RAM). What you are doing is like saying:

```
if (0x0800001000 == 0x090000000) {
...
}
```

which is always going to be false (unless something really weird happens)

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do, but there are two possibilities

1. You want to compare the first string passed in on the command line to "a"

```
// do it like this
if (strcmp(argv[1],"a") == 0) {
...
}
```

2. You want to compare the first character of the first string passed in on the command line to 'a'

```
// do it like this
if (argv[1][0] == 'a') {
...
}
```

We use argv[1] because argv[0] is just the name of the executable

Comment: But why the statement ```"a" == "a"``` is true, they don't come from different address?

Comment: Well, I‘ve tested it and they do come from same address

Comment: Your compiler is clever and is optimising string storage

Comment: @oo there is no guarantee that "a" and the second "a" will be at the same address.